# JPA/Hibernate hangs on production during EntityManagerFactory creation

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

We have strange problem. Since couple of days, creation of `EntityManagerFactory` takes randomly from couple of seconds to couple minutes (even 30 and more!)

This is part of `TRACE` logs:

```
12:36:49.281 [main] INFO  [org.hibernate.Version               ] - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.10.Final}
12:36:49.288 [main] INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment       ] - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
12:36:49.295 [main] DEBUG [hibernate.service.spi.ServiceBinding] - Overriding existing service binding [org.hibernate.secure.spi.JaccService]
12:36:49.305 [main] TRACE [internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl] - Initializing service [role=org.hibernate.engine.config.spi.ConfigurationService]
12:36:49.309 [main] TRACE [internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl] - Initializing service [role=org.hibernate.cache.spi.RegionFactory]
12:36:49.310 [main] DEBUG [ache.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator] - Cache region factory : org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCachingRegionFactory
12:36:49.316 [main] INFO  [hibernate.annotations.common.Version] - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
12:36:49.319 [main] TRACE [internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl] - Initializing service [role=org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.spi.CfgXmlAccessService]

//HERE IT SIMPLY HANGS
```

What could be the cause? I have double check locks on DB and there are none.

POM:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

`${hibernate.version}` is `5.2.10.Final` Using MySQL 5.6.17.

Persistence.xml

```
  <properties>
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ourdbname?useSSL=false"/>
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="ouruser" />
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="ourpassword" />
          <property name="hibernate.connection.verifyServerCertificate" value="false" />
          <property name="hibernate.connection.requireSSL" value="false"/>
          <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
          <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect"/>
          <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="utf-8"/>
          <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true" />
          <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/>
          <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
          <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size" value="10"/>
          <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer" value="false"/>
          <property name="hibernate.c3p0.validate" value="true"/>
          <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider"/>
          <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="4"/>
          <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="10"/>
          <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="1800"/>
          <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="0"/>
          <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="200"/>
          <property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery" value="SELECT 1;"/>
  </properties>
```

We cannot connect any application changes to the beginnig for such bhavior as there were no changes to DB schema nor model.

Creation of `EMF`

```
EntityManagerFactory factory=javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(puName);
```

EDIT:

Thread dump reveals that process hangs on native file system call. Any workaround for that?

```
"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000010c9000 nid=0x2c73 runnable [0x00007f4c928f5000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.list(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.list(File.java:1122)
    at java.io.File.listFiles(File.java:1207)
    at org.hibernate.boot.archive.internal.ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.processDirectory(ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.boot.archive.internal.ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.processDirectory(ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.boot.archive.internal.ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.visitArchive(ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.AbstractScannerImpl.scan(AbstractScannerImpl.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.internal.ScanningCoordinator.coordinateScan(ScanningCoordinator.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.prepare(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:227)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:36)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:52)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
```

Comment: Errors that delay execution so much are usually caused by socket connection timeouts. Did you make sure to allow the 3306 port local access in your firewall?

Comment: That is possitive, firewall configuration have not been touches for years (literally). I am able to get to the database from MysqlWorkbench as well. The funny part is that is stops on service creation not related with connection pool creation (at least not in know way to me)

Comment: @coladict Hey, chan you see my update? I turns out to be related to linux filesystem operations. Any idea how to walkaround this?

Comment: Well then, maybe it's a problem with file permissions, since it hangs when listing files. It's probably waiting on some permission that it's not getting.