# JPA/Hibernate hangs on native filesystem operations during boot

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

This is a followup of [JPA/Hibernate hangs on production during EntityManagerFactory creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43608812/jpa-hibernate-hangs-on-production-during-entitymanagerfactory-creation)

I have managed to get a thread dump during "hanging" state and I have discovered that the problem is related to file system listing operation.

In general, this process can hang in this state during application bootstrap for couple (~30) minutes. Any walkawrounds or fixes for this??

```
"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000010c9000 nid=0x2c73 runnable [0x00007f4c928f5000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.list(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.list(File.java:1122)
    at java.io.File.listFiles(File.java:1207)
    at org.hibernate.boot.archive.internal.ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.processDirectory(ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.boot.archive.internal.ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.processDirectory(ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.boot.archive.internal.ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.visitArchive(ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.AbstractScannerImpl.scan(AbstractScannerImpl.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.internal.ScanningCoordinator.coordinateScan(ScanningCoordinator.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.prepare(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:227)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:36)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:52)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
```

Comment: It may help people help you if you include some more information. Is this happening on a workstation/VM/Docker? Is there any special with the file system (e.g. NFS)? Any SE Linux extensions? Anything else that might be "strange" you can think of? Java version/Linux distro? I am doing everyday development on Linux (with Java, Hibernate) and this does not occur, but other strange things have happened in rare circumstances!

Comment: I have a similar issue with a similar stack trace but I see the stack trace along with an OutOfMemoryError. Same app deployed in jar files instead of .class files on the file system, no problem. But on my dev server, where I deploy .class files directly, I see the OOME. @Antoniossss Did you get any further on this in the meantime?

Comment: @marc82ch unfortunetly I cannot recall right now, and I have moved to different project ;(

Comment: I figured it out in my case, the problem was that . (the current directory) was part of the classpath and I was launching programs when inside a rather large directory. Hibernate probably needs to scan all files in the whole classpath directory structure to find entity classes. I don't fully understand it, but something like that, probably.

Comment: Yes exactly. As I recall now, the log files directory was on the classpath. Moving it out of it solved the issue! Im glad u did find it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem for me as well as for marc82ch was having enomerous count of files (external) on the application classpath. For instance, in my case I had log files directory included in classpath with tons of files.